# RTK Query - Possibility to reset isLoading value?

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

We have an 'Infinite Scrolling' functionality in our current App. How this currently works is that we request an amount of posts from the API service using a parameter `count` which we increase by 25 each time that the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

This works quite nicely, upon first page load a FullScreen spinner is shown. When reaching the max scrolling depth, a smaller spinner is shown while the query is now fetching an additional 25 posts.

However, if we want change the `threadId` value, ideally the App would then show the fullScreen spinner once more. We can achieve this by using isFetching in place of isLoading, but then we will render that Spinner each time the user reaches the end of page.

Ideally, we would want `isFetching` to be true if the `count` parameter changes, and `isLoading` to be true if the threadId parameter changes.

What would be the recommended way to approach this?

```
const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetPostsQuery({ count: 25 * pageNumber, threadId })

if (isLoading) {
  return <Spinner isFullScreen />
}

if (data?.length) {
  return (
    <>
      ...Content
      {isFetching && <Spinner variant='sm' />}
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a combination of isFetching and currentData

```
const { data, isFetching, currentData } = useGetPostsQuery({ count: 25 * pageNumber, threadId })

if (isFetching && !currentData) {
  return <Spinner isFullScreen />
}

if (data?.length) {
  return (
    <>
      ...Content
      {isFetching && <Spinner variant='sm' />}
    </>
}
```

You can read more about [managing UI with currentData](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#query-loading-state) in the docs